# Andrew runs 6 miles everyday of the week except Sunday.

Tags: combinatorics

Can anyone work this out for me?

Andrew runs 6 miles everyday of the week except Sunday. After his run on Monday, July 4, 2011, his cumulative total miles run reached 4224. What day did Andrew start running 6 miles per day?

Comment: Have you tried to work it out yourself? As it is now, your question reads as "*do my homework for me.*"

Comment: Andrew's knees are probably broken.

Answer (score 0):

Every week, he runs $6*6=36$ miles. So he has ran $\left \lfloor 4224/36\right \rfloor =117$ weeks. The remainder of $4224/36$ is $12$ miles, so he ran $2$ more days in addition to those $117$ weeks. Because the day he runs $4244$ miles is a Monday, we can go back two days, skipping Sunday because he doesn't run on Sunday, to get Saturday. So Andrew started running on a Saturday. Looking at my calendar, this Saturday is April 4th, 2009.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got to the remainder 12 and did not see that it would be two extra days.